# Show oci_parse'd statement

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, pecl, oracle-call-interface

Is there a way to show the SQL statement that has just been ociparse'd (with or without bound variables)? I maintain a legacy application and sometimes the SQL is built from many different places and lots of conditionals in between. I'd preferably do a print_r($handle) but of course that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.
There is no simple way for debug a parsed query via native function.
You need to create your own wrapper

Comment: Funny I haven't found any relevant discussion or any existing library/wrapper that does it already.